# Showing that $K[x,y,z]/(y^2 - xz) \simeq K[x,y,\frac{y^2}{x}]$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field and consider the ideal $(y^2 - xz) \lhd K[x,y,z]$. Intuitively, it seems clear to me that $K[x,y,z]/(y^2 - xz)$ should be isomorphic to the subring $K[x,y,\frac{y^2}{x}]$ of $K(x,y) = \text{Frac}(K[x,y])$. The only way I can think of showing this is to take the obvious map $\varphi: K[x,y,z] \rightarrow K[x,y,\frac{y^2}{x}]$ and show that $\ker\varphi = (y^2 -xz)$. Of course $(y^2 -xz) \subseteq \ker\varphi$ is clear, but I have problems with showing containment in the other direction. More precisely, I probably could just "brute-force" it, but I feel that there must be a more elegant way of showing this, given that the conclusion seems so obvious.

Is there a "nice" way to show either $\ker \varphi \subseteq (y^2 - xz)$, or directly that $K[x,y,z]/(y^2 - xz) \simeq K[x,y,\frac{y^2}{x}]$? I would be particularly happy to learn general techniques that can be used in similar situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write $$f(x,y,z)=(z-y^2/x)g(y,z)+r(y)$$ with $g\in k(x)[y,z]$ and $r\in k(x)[y]$. Multiplying by $xh(x)$ we get $$xh(x)f(x,y,z)=(xz-y^2)h(x)g(y,z)+xh(x)r(y),$$ where $h\in k[x]$ is chosen with the property $h(x)g(y,z),h(x)r(y)\in k[x,y,z]$. Since $f(x,y,y^2/x)=0$ we have $xh(x)r(y)=0$, so $r=0$. Thus $xh(x)f(x,y,z)\in(xz-y^2)$. But the ideal $(xz-y^2)$ is prime, and $x,h(x)\not\in(xz-y^2)$, so $f\in(xz-y^2)$.